# Scala List of String Option[String] using with mkString

Tags: scala

I have a List which can have a String or Option[String]

like this

```
val a = List("duck","dog","cat")

a.mkString(:)

duck:dog:cat

val b = List(Some("duck"), "dog", None)
```

and my output should be

"duck:dog"

How can I do that, I get some aproximation with this:

```
scala> a.map{ x =>
     | x match {
     | case x:String => x
     | case Some(x:String) => x
     | case None => null}}

List[String] = List(duck, dog, null)

scala> res.filter(_!=null).mkString(":")
res24: String = duck:dog
```

Is there a better way, of doing that?

Comment: Ideally you would fix whatever if giving you a `List[Any]`.

Comment: Can you have a `null` instead of a `None`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect example to use `collect`.
We would like to create a list with only part of the elements, and then we would like to use `mkString`:

```
val b = List(Some("duck"), "dog", None)

val result: List[String] = b collect {
  case x: String => x
  case Some(x: String) => x
}
result.mkString(":")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `flatMap` to get rid of the `filter`:

```
  b.flatMap {
    case x: String => List(x)
    case Some(x) => List(x)
    case None => List()
  }.mkString(":")
```

or you could `filter` before the `map`:

```
  b.filter(_ != None).map {
    case x: String => x
    case Some(x) => x
  }.mkString(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that's safe for `null`

```
scala> val l = List(Some("duck"), "dog", None, null)
l: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(Some(duck), dog, None, null)

scala> l.map{a => a match { 
       | case null => "" 
       | case Some(a) => Some(a).get.toString 
       | case None => "" 
       | case _ => a.toString}}.filter(_.length > 0).mkString(":")

res7: String = duck:dog
```